# Upper bound on a function with holder continuous gradient.

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, convex-geometry

Let $f : \mathbb R^d \to \mathbb R$ be differentiable with Holder continuous gradient, *ie*, there exists $L < \infty$ and $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ such that

$$ \|  \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\| \le L \| x - y\|^\alpha \quad \forall x, y\in \mathbb R^d.$$

Then how to show that

$$f(y) \le f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle + \frac{L}{1 + \alpha} \|y-x\|^{1+\alpha} \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb R^d.$$

Comment: Look for the proof of the Descent Lemma. A small adaptation will give you the desired result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct inequality should be
\begin{equation}f(y) \le f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle + \frac{L}{1 + \alpha} \|y-x\|^{1+\alpha} \quad \forall x, y \in \mathbb R^d.
\end{equation}
Otherwise take $x^2$ as a counter-example.

The common trick to handle this kind of inequalities is to notice that
\begin{equation}f(y) - f(x) = \int_0^1 \langle \nabla f(x + t(y-x)), y-x\rangle dt,
\end{equation}
and thus
\begin{equation}f(y) - f(x) - \langle\nabla f(x), y-x\rangle= \int_0^1 \langle \nabla f(x + t(y-x)) - \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle dt,
\end{equation}
It should be simple enough for you from here, but just in case:
\begin{align}|f(y) - f(x) - \langle\nabla f(x), y-x\rangle | &\le \int_0^1 |\langle \nabla f(x + t(y-x)) - \nabla f(x), y-x\rangle |dt \\
&\le \int_0^1 \|\nabla f(x + t(y-x)) - \nabla f(x)\| \|y-x\|dt \\
&\le \int_0^1 L\|t(y-x)\|^\alpha \|y-x\|dt \\
&= L\|y-x\|^{1+\alpha} \int_0^1 t^\alpha dt \\
&= \frac{L}{1+\alpha}\|y-x\|^{1+\alpha}.
\end{align}