# How to prove that the gradient of nonconvex smooth function is Lipschitz continuous?

Tags: convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization, lipschitz-functions

Given a 1-smooth and nonconvex function $f(x)$, satisfy
$$f(y) - f(x) -\left<\nabla f(x),y-x\right>\leq \frac{L}{2}\|x-y\|^2$$
How to prove that the gradient is Lipschitz continuous, i.e.,
$$\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)\|\leq L\|x-y\|$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every concave, smooth function $f$ satisfies your first inequality for $L = 0$. Hence, your claim is not true.

Comment: Do you mean that every concave function is not satisfies the second inequality?

Comment: No, but there exists at least one concave function which does not satisfy the second inequality.

Comment: I think that all concave smooth function is satisfies the second inequality, please see my  comment on @Khue.

Comment: This is not true. $x \mapsto |x|^{3/2}$ is convex and continuously differentiable, but the derivative is not Lipschitz.

Comment: I think it’s clear enough at this point. +1.

Comment: Thanks! I got it

Answer (score 0):

The statement is not true as @gerw has pointed out, just take any concave function as a counter-example. The converse, however, is true. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3854586/upper-bound-on-a-function-with-holder-continuous-gradient/3855516#3855516) for a proof.

Comment: For any concave smooth $f$, then $−f$ is a convex and smooth function, satisfies  $\|-\nabla f(x) - (-\nabla(y)) \|\leq L \|x-y\|$. That is  $\|\nabla f(x) - \nabla(y) \|\leq L \|x-y\|$. i.e., every concave smooth function is satisfies the second inequality.

Comment: @Kadeng Just set $L=0$ then you’ll see that the implication is wrong.